# Запуск Toast, при запуске самого приложения

Tags: android, android-toast

Как однократно вызвать всплывающее уведомление при запуске приложения, не нажимая на кнопки?

Comment: Запустить в любом из методов: `onCreate` или `onResume`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При старте приложение всегда вызывается метод [`Application#onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()), его и можно использовать для показа `Toast`:

```java
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Started!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <application android:name=".App">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```